# Error when running pub get: Failed to rename directory because it was in use by another process

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I get the below error when I try to get packages of beautifulsoup in my dart console project.

```
[scrape_3] pub get
Resolving dependencies...
+ beautifulsoup 0.0.1
Downloading beautifulsoup 0.0.1...
Failed to rename directory because it was in use by another process.
This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file
in the directory open in another application.
exit code 1
```

My `pubspec.yaml` file is  as follows:

```
    name: scrape_3
    description: A sample command-line application.
    # version: 1.0.0
    # homepage: https://www.example.com
    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"
    
    #dependencies:
    #  path: ^1.7.0
    dev_dependencies:
      pedantic: ^1.9.0
      test: ^1.14.4
    dependencies:
      beautifulsoup: ^0.0.1
      html: ^0.13.3+3
```

How can I solve this? this is a recurring error for me and happens often.

Comment: Based on the error code and assuming your on Windows. 1. Try running `pub get` with admin rights. 2. Try disabling windows defender. 3. If none of the above work, try restarting your computer.

Comment: I did all of the above and nothing worked @MendelG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shutting down PC and starting it back on after some minutes **eventually worked**. Apparently, the file stays in use by VS CODE itself for a while and direct Restarts don't work

Answer (score 2):

Just reset changes on your "pubspec.lock".
Or simply delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to close VSCode, open it as Admin, then run `flutter get` again.

As an extra precaution I had also made sure I didn't have any of the flutter/dart tools running in command lines, powershell etc and no File Explorer windows open.

Answer (score 0):

If you using android studio
1.restart you laptop/pc.
2.close your antivirus if exist.
3.run android studio as administration and try again.